# What does the array_filter key in $form do?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm following [this tutorial on creating a settings form](https://youtu.be/2UbzDZiyK7M) for a module in Drupal 8. The instructions say to implement the `buildForm` method of `ConfigFormBase` in the following way:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Request $request = NULL) {
    $types = node_type_get_names();
    $config = $this->config('rsvplist.settings');
    $form['rsvplist_types'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => $this->t('The content types to enable RSVP collection for'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('allowed_types'),
      '#options' => $types,
      '#description' => t('On the specified node types, an RSVP option will be available and can be enabled while that node is being edited.'),
    );

    $form['array_filter'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => TRUE);

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
```

Everything here makes sense to me except I can't find any documentation on the role that they `'array_filter'` key in the `$form` variable plays. What does this value do? Where is it documented?

Comment: Consider switching to the short array syntax. Same as behind the link to the settings form in my answer. It's also coding standard now, see [Arrays should be formatted using short array syntax](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#array).

Comment: @leymannx I wasn't aware that this notation existed, thanks for that. It's much neater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice catch! It does nothing. You can safely remove it. Looks like some kind of forgotten relict.

Ah, yeah. The same pattern can be found in core's book module: [`BookSettingsForm.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.0.5/core/modules/book/src/Form/BookSettingsForm.php#L50).

And there is a 12(!) years old open issue to have it removed. [[#315176] Clean-up remains of $form['array_filter'] hack with array_filter in book module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/315176)